# How to clear all tha data each time the app is accessed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I actually want to my database entries to be empty each time the app is accessed. But i am not getting any idea regarding this. Below is my code which takes 3 inputs from user and displays them in tabular form but each time I display the table old entries are also getting displayed. I want that once all the entries are displayed the database should get cleared.

```
<p>enter the name with registration number of students</p>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/pages/add" method="post">
<input id="nam" name="nam" type="text">
<input id="reg" name="reg" type="text">
<input id="cls" name="cls" type="text">
<input name="commit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Add todo">
</form>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>REGISTRATION NUMBER</th>
<th>CLASSES ATTENDED</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<% @pages.each do |t| %>
<td><%= t.name_student %></td>
<td><%= t.reg_no %></td>
<td><%= t.classes_at %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Did I get it right? you just want to display the data that the user has submitted? Then use the params to display them and don't save anything to the db

Comment: Not getting you. You want to display entries for particular session or single entry that user added each time. independent of session ?

Comment: Sounds client-side JavaScript would suit better, not Rails. It's just not the right tool for the job. Rendering sent parameters is a great idea as well. Why use persistent storage if you don't need it at all? Database is a heavy burden for the server.